# Conservation theorem for cyclic coordinates in the Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, noethers-theorem

Suppose $q_1,q_2,...,q_j,..,q_n$ are the generalized coordinates of a system.
$q_j$ is not there in the Lagrangian (it is cyclic).
Then $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_j}=constant$

In Goldstein, it has been proved that if $q_j$ is such that if it is changed by $\epsilon$, then all other coordinates also gets changed by the same amount in the direction of $q_j$ (whole system gets translated). In such a case, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_j}$ is the component of total momentum in the direction of $q_j$.

**DOUBT**
I have doubt that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_j}$ as the component of total momentum in the direction of $q_j$ is for any cyclic coordinate or only for that cyclic coordinate whose displacement causes the same displacement of the system in that direction?
I am trying to prove that.

**MY WORK**
$\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_j}=\sum_i m_i\dot r_i\frac{\partial\dot r_i}{\partial\dot q_j}$
$\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_j}=\sum_i m_i\dot r_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}$

I am not sure whether in general $\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}=\epsilon\hat n$.
where $\epsilon$ is the displacement in $q_j$ and $\hat n$ is the unit vector in the direction of displacement of $q_j$.

Comment: *if qj is such that if it is changed by ϵ, then all other coordinates also gets changed by the same amount in the direction of qj* Could you point to specific page? This doesn't make any sense to me. First of all, the whole point of coordinates is that they are independent. If you move along one, the others remain constant. When you move in x direction in cartesian system, y and z keep constant. Could you just misunderstood something?

Comment: P.No 57 of Goldstein classical mechanics 2nd edition. Here all other coordinates refers to the euclidean coordinates of the particles ($r_i$ not $q_i$) on the system not the generalized coordinates.

Comment: there is no vector in Lagrangian mechanics your expression with $\hat n$ does not make sense as the LHS is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

First, to clear the confusion about translation, when one shifts one of the coordinates of the system, you are translating the entire system. For example, consider a particle placed on a 2D plane with coordinates $(x,y)$. Now the system, which in this case is the particle itself, can be translated by shifting $x$. So, the new set of coordinates are $(x+\epsilon, y)$. So, shifting a single coordinate automatically amounts to shifting the whole system.

Second, regarding the cyclic variable. By definition, when the position coordinate for a variable $q_j$ does not appear in the Lagrangian, it implies that the conjugate momentum, defined by $p_j = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}$ is conserved. This follows from the Euler Lagrange equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j}
$$

where the term on the right hand side turns out to be zero. So, as long as the variable is cyclic, its conjugate momentum is conserved. This results from the fact that the Lagrangian is independent of translations in the coordinate $q_j$.

> Blockquote
> I have doubt that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}$ as the component of total momentum in the direction of qj is for any cyclic coordinate or only for that cyclic coordinate whose displacement causes the same displacement of the system in that direction?

Your question is not clear, as it seems to be unrelated to the property of a variable being cyclic. Because, following the definition of conjugate momentum we know that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}$ is giving momentum along the direction $q_j$. That quantity in general, is not related to the momenta in other directions.

Comment: Actually I am confused that what the author is trying to conclude by the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

> In Goldstein, it has been proved that if $q_j$ is such that if it is changed by $\epsilon$, then all other coordinates also gets changed by the same amount in the direction of $q_j$ (whole system gets translated). In such a case, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_j}$ is the component of total momentum in the direction of $q_j$.

> **DOUBT**
> I have doubt that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q_j}$ as the component of total momentum in the direction of $q_j$ is for any cyclic coordinate or only for that cyclic coordinate whose displacement causes the same displacement of the system in that direction?
> I am trying to prove that.

> **MY WORK**
> $\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_j}=\sum_i m_i\dot r_i\frac{\partial\dot r_i}{\partial\dot q_j}$
> $\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_j}=\sum_i m_i\dot r_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}$

It is not clear what you are trying to show in the "My Work" section. Are you trying to *derive* the Lagrangian equations of motion for a conservative system
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_j}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = 0
$$
from Newton's second law?

If you are willing to presume the correctness of the above Lagrangian equations of motion, then your conservation result follows *immediately* from the *definition* of a cyclic coordinate $q_r$:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_r}\equiv 0
$$
and the *definition* of the canonical momentum for that coordinate:
$$
p_r \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_r}
$$

---

Alternatively, if you are actually trying to *derive* the Lagrangian equations of motion starting from Newton's 2nd law, you would proceed by next considering
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_j} = \sum_i m_i\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot r_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)
$$
$$
=\sum_i m_i\left(\ddot r_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}
+\dot r_i\frac{\partial \dot r_i}{\partial q_j}
\right)\;,
$$
where, next, you will find that the second term above cancels out when you subtract off $\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}$ and you will find that:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j} = F^{ext}_j\;,
$$
where
$$
F^{ext}_j\delta q_j
$$
is the infinitesimal work $\delta W$ performed by the external forces when $q_j \to q_j + \delta q_j$ with all other $q_i$ fixed.

Next, if you can write $F^{ext}_j$ as $-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}$ (i.e., conservative force), then you have derived the Lagrangian equations of motion, where $L=T-U$.

---

Reference: E. T. Whittaker "A Treatise on the Analytical Dynamics of Particles and Rigid bodies" (2nd Edition) Cambridge University Press (1917), especially at pages 34 - 38.

Comment: Actually I am confused that what the author is trying to conclude by the derivation.

Comment: *What* derivation? *Which* derivation?